# LeftAlign support actionBar with more icons on the right?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am trying to have an actionbar like this: [image: Actionbar]
As you can see, there are some icons on the left, no title or home icon and on the right there are more icons hidden. My question is, how to achieve this effect ? I know that i must use rhe custom layout for this but can't figure out how to properly style and override proper methods like OnOptionsItemSelected(). So far I have

```
 getSupportActionBar().setShowTitleEnabeled(false);
```

Comment: The items to the left are custom tabs.  Are you looking to add tabs or icons to the left?

Comment: I would prefer tabs but icons are also good

Comment: Okay then I will post a little mock setup of how that could be implemented. It is not going to be your generic setup.

Comment: Okay, I will try to understand that. Also take in conaideration that I have translucent action and systembar

Answer (score 0):

use this for remove back button:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

and this for right menu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_overflow"
    android:icon=""
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="t3">
    <menu>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_contact"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            android:title="tt"/>


        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu2"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            android:title="t2"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu1"
            android:icon=""
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            android:title="t1"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: but i want that icons aligned to the left mainly